# composer status doesn't display the local changes and composer update doesn't regenerate the package

Tags: php, composer-php

I am confused with the behaviour of the **composer status** command, `composer help` says:

```
status               Shows a list of locally modified packages.
```

So, I start a new empty project and require some package:

```
~/project$ composer require mustache/mustache
Using version ^2.12 for mustache/mustache
./composer.json has been created
  - Installing mustache/mustache (v2.12.0): Loading from cache
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

Let's do some changes (remove one file from that package and change another one) and let's run again `composer status`:

```
~/project$ rm vendor/mustache/mustache/README.md 
~/project$ echo '// Some change' >> vendor/mustache/mustache/src/Mustache/Engine.php 
~/project$ composer status
No local changes
```

It says that there was no local changes. I was expecting **composer status** to tell me that *README.md* was removed and *Engine.php* was changed.

If I run composer update, nothing happens:

```
~/project$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
~/project$ ls vendor/mustache/mustache/README.md
ls: cannot access vendor/mustache/mustache/README.md: No such file or directory
```

The only way I know to restore the original package is by removing the vendor/ dir and running **composer install** again.

Why **composer status** doesn't display the local changes, and why **composer update** doesn't restore the original package? I'm using composer 1.6.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`composer status` only supports packages installed from source, not from downloaded ZIP files. This is also a reason why Composer doesn't perform the update of the package (i.e. not being able to detect any changes in packages coming from `dist` repo).

There was already an issue concerning this on Composer GitHub repo: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5500

Comment: Thank you. I think it would be clearer if they put in the help command that warning.

Comment: `composer status` support zip-files from 1.7, sometimes with a "chdir()" bug that was fixed in 1.7.3

Answer (score 0):

Even though it seemed like this is not implemented, it believe that it works now. During `composer status` composer creates special checkout with `_compare` suffix to compare the versions:

```
Executing command (CWD): unzip -qq  '/var/www/html/legacy-app/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php_compare/ba39e4a340165876e4355a19f89fe81f' -d '/var/www/html/legacy-app/vendor/composer/fd8c9a79'
```